# d3.json() is not loading data on asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I've been experimenting with d3.js, for example on force-directed graph there is the following sample code:

```
d3.json("file.json", function (error, graph) {

  force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();
```

I'm using asp.net MVC, so I tried to create the json file with an ActionResult like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult visualizationdata()
    {
        FileInfo  file= new FileInfo(Path.Combine( HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath , @"Content\visualizationdata.json"));

        return File(file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/json", "visualizationdata.json");
    }
```

Inside my cshtml with the example of d3 I have:

```
d3.json("@Url.Action("visualizationdata")" //the rest of the example code in d3.js
```

the json file content is this:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"1","group":1},
    {"name":"2","group":1},
    //just json format (but no variable receiving it)
```

With a get request as "/controller/visualizationdata" the file gets rendered just fine

***SOLUTION***: provided by mates at stackoverflow

Just change the version from 2 to 3: http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

Comment: Which D3 library version are you loading? Are you using d3.v2.js or d3.v3.js?

Comment: I'd bet you're importing d3.v2, but the format you're using is for d3.v3. If you're using d3.v2, then just remove "error" from your list of parameters. d3.v2 expects the first paramter of the .json callback to be the var to store the data in.

Comment: guys, THANK YOU SOOO MUCH.... I spent too much time staring at the computer with philosophical thinking about extensions on MVC