# D3.js does not render SVG in ASP MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, d3.js

I've got a d3.js script which renders just fine in a .html document outside my app but when I embed it in a .cshtml file inside an mvc app the svg is blank.  Can someone help me understand why this isn't rendering?  Javascript console in both Chrome and IE show no errors. Thanks

Here is the dom:

```
<svg width="1920" height="1000">
    <rect class="background" width="1920" height="1000"/>
    <g transform="translate(960 500)">
        <g id="states"/>
```

The .cshtml is:

```
<style>

.background {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
    fill: green;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

#pct {
    stroke: blue;
    fill: blue;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

#states .active {
    fill: steelblue;
}

</style>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var height = 1000,
    width = 1920,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
        .scale(width)
        .translate([0,0]);

var path = d3.geo.path("~/Map_Data/states.geojson")
        .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "states");

 d3.json("@(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Map_Data/states.geojson"))", function (data) {
    g.selectAll("path").data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("id", "states");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can try with `d3.geo.path("@(Url.Content("~/Map_Data/states.geojson"))")`

Comment: I tried but the resulting html is exactly the same as what I had in the original and had the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is there at `/Map_Data/states.geojson`? So if you try to open that url directly in your browser does it opens your file?

Comment: I get a file permission error when directly opening the file in the browser.  Am i missing a setting which allows the app to access this dir? Thanks

Comment: I made sure i have access to the /Map_data/states.geojson and I am still not getting any content rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gleaned most of the answer from this post: [d3.json() is not loading data on asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870599/d3-json-is-not-loading-data-on-asp-net-mvc)

The d3.json method only takes URLs so you need to provide an action to read the file and expose it with a url per the link above.  It will not work if you use a file path.

Comment: I just used http://domain.com/scripts/flare.json - worked great, no action method needed.