# Passing a CSV/TSV file to D3 using MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, csv, d3.js

I'm going through the tutorial at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/

The example code (below) shows a relative file name, `"data.tsv"`, of the data file to be passed to the D3 function.  However I need to pass this file via an MVC controller.  How can I do this?

`d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {...`

Anything would be a big help, thanks.

Update:

The `"data.tsv" and "data.json"` routes were a bust.  I tried for two days to get the data sent from a MVC controller to the `d3`method to work, but I couldn't get it to bind properly.

However I used `jQuery.ajax` to get the data (json) from the server and that worked first time.  :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? What do you mean by MVC controller? Is the data going to from a file or generated dynamically?

Comment: The data could be generated dynamically if possible, however if this is not possible it could come from a file.

Comment: Ok, so you specify the URL the data will be generated at in the first argument.

Comment: Yes, and I can get it to call a controllers method AND get that controller to pass back information to the client (viewed in firebug).  However D3 doesn't display it.

Comment: Have you verified that D3 parses it correctly (i.e. have a look at `error`)? Is the data format different?

Comment: Then the data format must be different.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to figure it out how to pass a file (CSV, TSV or Json) to a d3.js graph I found  [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870599/d3-json-is-not-loading-data-on-asp-net-mvc).

Basically you need to create a **new** method in your controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]    
public ActionResult GetCSV()
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"data.csv"));
        return File(file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "text/csv", "data.csv");
    }
```

In the first line add the correct path, so f.e. if your file you would like to load is in the folder "Content" in your project folder then the first line must be

```
FileInfo(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"Content/data.csv"));
```

The second line needs to contain the right MIME type (third argument) and the name of the file (fourth argument). After specifying this in your controller, go to the view and add

```
d3.csv("@Url.Action("GetCSV")", type, function(error, data) {...
```

Here you had an example for CSV files, but it works the same way for TSV and Json with `d3.tsv(...)` and `d3.json(...)` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "data.tsv" file is stored in the `assets` folder. Since d3 is a client-side library, the data file must be made public for the d3 to access it (and putting it in assets makes it public).

Here's some information on Assets: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/assets